# Is $f(0) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) - f(n-1)$ equal to $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ or $0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If I have a sum for which I remove the previous iteration every time, then I am left with only the last iteration of the sum: $$f(0) + \sum_{n=1}^x f(n) - f(n-1) = f(x)$$

If this would be a sum to infinity, then I am left with the $\infty$th iteration, which can be also written as a limit: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$

That sum can also be split into two sums to infinity, which gives the following: $$f(0) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n-1)$$
I could then rewrite that as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty-1} f(n)$$

Because $\infty - 1$ gives $\infty$, the two sums cancel out, giving $0$.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking it up into two series only makes sense if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f(n)$ converges.  And if it converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$. Hence there is no inconsistency here.